# c++ : calling a variables of a class from another class

Tags: c++

I have a class lets say

```
class ABC
{
   int x;
   char y;
  ....
}
```

another class

```
class xyz{
   int UseVariablOfABC(int a,char b)
   // a and b are the variables/members declared in class ABC above
}

int xyz::UseVariablOfABC(int a,char b){
//Do some thing with a and b
}
```

xyz class is abstracted from the user(means he cant set the value of arguments of its member function here it is useVariableofABC ), user can  only use ABC class .... Is it posible in c++... Do i need create a object of class ABC in xyz ......

any suggestions plz ........

Comment: Define a method in ABC to return you the values of x and y

Answer (score 0):

If the members of `ABC` aren't `static`, then yes, you do need an instance. And if you only want the arguments of `xyz::UseVariablOfABC` to be members of `ABC`, just pass that instance as parameter instead:

```
int xyz::UseVariablOfABC(const ABC&)
```